# Keras SavedModel vs Tensorflow SavedModel

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflowjs-converter

I'm reading the [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter#format-conversion-support-tables) and source code of the TensorflowJS converter and it makes a clear distinction between Keras SavedModel and Tensorflow SavedModel.

What are the differences between the formats and what is the cross-format support story?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to:

```
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#:~:text=Saving%20custom%20objects,-If%20you%20are&text=The%20key%20difference%20between%20HDF5,without%20requiring%20the%20orginal%20code.
```

It discusses the differences

Comment: I think your link describes the difference between the Keras HDF5 model and SavedModel, not between two kinds of SavedModel. Right before your quote: 'If you are using the SavedModel format, you can skip this section."